# allow All trafic to and from the instance using boto

Tags: boto

The following code works as expected.

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='zzz')

sg = conn.create_security_group('test_delete', 'description')
auth = conn.authorize_security_group(sg.name, None, None, ip_protocol='tcp', from_port='22', to_port='22', cidr_ip='0.0.0.0/0')
```

I can select "**All traffic**" option from user interface. There is no equivalent here in boto. 
I am aware of the security risks involved, but for some reason I want to open all ports (to / from) for all traffic using boto.

Answer (score 2):

use 'IpProtocol': '-1'  for "All traffic" option, see below code for details.

```
def create_ingress_rules (credentials=None,securitygroupid=None, region_name=None):

print("3-Start creating ingress rule(s)...")

create_ingress_rules_handler = \
    boto3.client('ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    region_name=region_name)


try:
    data = create_ingress_rules_handler.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=securitygroupid,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': '-1',
            'FromPort': 0,
            'ToPort': 65535,
            'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0','Description': 'Temporary inbound rule for Guardrail Testing'}]}
        ])

    print('Complete creating Ingress rule...')
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: This works, but if you specify `-1`, you aren't allowed to specify the `FromPort` and `ToPort` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to specify the min and max values for a port number.  Since it is a 16-bit value, the value can range from 0 to 65535.  So:

```
auth = conn.authorize_security_group(sg.name, None, None, ip_protocol='tcp', from_port=0, to_port=65535, cidr_ip='0.0.0.0/0')
```

Should allow traffic on all ports for the TCP protocol.